# How to change elements for the child elements inside a user control. - In the designer

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls

Well I made my custom usercontrol which is "simply" a combination of a label and a textbox.

```
<UserControl x:Class="testit.LabelTextBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="30" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox" TextWrapping="Wrap" DockPanel.Dock="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding TextBoxText}" />
        <Label x:Name="label" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Target="{x:Reference textBox}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Label Text"/>
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

I then created a usercontrol class with the dependecy property:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace simtest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for LabelTextBox.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class LabelTextBox : UserControl
    {
        public string TextBoxText {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TextBoxTextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextBoxTextProperty, value); }
        }

        public readonly static DependencyProperty TextBoxTextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("TextBoxTextProperty",
                typeof(string), typeof(LabelTextBox), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
        public LabelTextBox() {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }
    }
}
```

Now this "works" as in that it compiles. And if I use above control as:

```
<local:LabelTextBox TextBoxText="foobar"></local:LabelTextBox>
```

It will show correctly - while running -.

However I need this for each and every element of the textbox I wish to be able to adapt - height width etc etc. This isn't really ideal: can I make it so that I can just edit the LabelTextBox' TextBox directly?

Comment: I don't know if I understand you correctly. You could create a style for your `LabelTextBox` and than simply apply that style to the `LabelTextBox`es which should look the same... Is that an option?

Comment: @MatthiasHerrmann Well that would be sidestepping the problem; I still won't have direct access to the label/textbox text and other elements that aren't updated with the style.